# How to rotate single vertex of nurbs path?

Tags: bezier-curves

I've been googling around trying to figure out how this is done.
But all I've managed to find from multiple sources, is that it basically can't be done.
Yet I'm literally half following along with a video where the individual seemingly does exactly that. They select a nurbs path, tab into edit mode, select a single vertex at the end of the
path, tap R to rotate and voilà.

They do have proportional editing on but I've tried that and it doesn't seem to make the difference. As far as I can tell my nurbs path is setup exactly the same way as theirs.
I've checked through add-ons and can't seem to find anything that would suggest it grants the ability to do this. I'm completely at a loss.

For reference here is the video:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TwWWTj2AMI&list=RDCMUCnXU0MjnApXHZkf3uGYbLSA&index=4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XUR0.jpg)
The action in question takes place at 13:10.

Edit: Here is my attempt to recreate what is seen in the video.
Scrolling mouse wheel has no effect on proportional edit radius. [image]

Here is the exact moment in the video I'm struggling to understand.
They didn't use alt + S or ctrl + T. Simply R to rotate.
At least that's what the screencast keys is showing. As
well as the portion of the interface in the upper left that displays the influence of edits. Meters of a move, angle of a rotation etc.
Somehow the proportional edit is working properly for them but for me it's acting as though I'm using it in an instance where it's void. [image]

Comment: It's hard to tell without having an idea of what exactly you tried to do, you should add a screenshot of your project where you actually try that or upload your blend file. I would suggest you to pay attention to the **influence radius** of the proportional editing though, if the radius is too small, you will see no difference when you rotate one vertex. You can adjust the radius with the mouse's scroll wheel.

Comment: as josh sanfelici says, you may be talking about the vertices radius? the shortcut is Alt S

Comment: Add a screenshot of your attempts as links are not enough

Comment: In your screenshot, the influence circle of the proportional editing is not visible so either it's too big (it's unlikely since the rotation doesn't affect the other vertices), either it's too small. So you should try to adjust it using your mouse wheel (Scrolling down makes the circle bigger). You may need to scroll for a little long before you see it.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka I tried that already. I believe the influence circle isn't visible because for some reason when I rotate it's ignoring the proportional edit altogether.
 If you look at the underlined portion of the interface in the upper left, you will see the modeler in the video I'm watching is rotating at a proportional influence size of 1.33 with a smooth falloff.
 Whereas in the screenshot of my attempt it just says rotating, but you can see I have proportional editing on.

Comment: You make a point there, could you share the blend file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=jWKnzvAW" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jWKnzvAW/)

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka First time posting here and sharing any of my work online so I'm not sure if I've done that right but I sure hope so.

Comment: You can upload your file at pasteall.org and then share the link here

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/6dc64ac1a9264662a47501c39fe1f2d4

Comment: I took a look on your file, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, **you have the pivot point set to individual origin** :

[image]

It can be seen on the screenshot you posted, I just didn't notice it :

[image]

And that rotates every single point around itself, which gives nothing.

You solve it by setting the pivot point to anything other than that, like `Median Point` (which is the default) :

[image]

And you will see the influence radius :

[image]

[image]

You can check the screenshot from the tutorial, he has it set on median point :

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I must have accidental hit a hotkey that changed it from the default because I certainly never intentionally, manually changed the pivot point.

Comment: You're welcome. The period key (alphanumeric pad) is the default hotkey for changing the pivot point, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

In this video the modeler uses 2 curves to model hair: one bezier circle defines the shape of the hair strand, while the Nurbs path defines its location and path.

Once established the rig, the Nurbs path gets edited with simple proportional editing, use the scroll wheel to vary its influence radius as Mqbaka suggested in the comments.

[image]

Also the radius of Nurbs vertices is taken into account.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that this was how I achieved initial shape of the path. I've edited my post and included a screenshot showing that this is exactly what I'm working with.